# tar folder without current folder

Tags: tar

When I tar my folder dist with file t.txt:

```
$ tar -czvf ../dist.tar.gz . 
./
./t.txt
```

I see that ./ added. Check

```
tar -ztvf dist.tar.gz.
```

show me two entry

```
./
./t.txt
```

How create archive without ./ folder?

Thank you!

Comment: Why? What problem do you think is caused by that `.`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by not letting `tar` process the `.` directory (and generate the files `./a.txt`, ...)

Let `bash` do the expansion:

```
tar -czvf dist.tar.gz *
```

Won't work if filenames contain spaces, or if there are too many filenames that are too long (see `xargs --show-limits </dev/null`)

Comment: This also excludes hidden files (i.e. files starting with `.`) in the current directory, correct?

Comment: Will work also if filenames contains spaces.

Comment: @PJSingh no, only what is "visible" is expanded. If you also want hidden files, you have to live with the "./" which in the end does not any harm.